# how to make visible table by clicking the textbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've created a numpad inside the table and setted the table visible false. I want to display the table after user clicked to the textbox. here is the code I wrote;

```
<div id="divTable"> 
                <table align="center"  runat="server" id="numpadTable" visible="false">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="1" OnClick="Button1_Click" CssClass="btnNumpad" /></td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="2" OnClick="Button2_Click" CssClass="btnNumpad" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="3" OnClick="Button3_Click" CssClass="btnNumpad" /></td>
            </tr></table></div>
```

textbox id= "numpadID";

I have found such codes to do that but I failed. For example;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#numpadID').live('click', function(event) {

        $('#numpadTable').toggle('show');

    });
});
</script>
```

It doesnt work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of live use 'on'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#numpadID').on('click', function(event) {

        $('#numpadTable').toggle('show');

    });
});
```

**Update Use This :-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#numpadID').on('click', function(event) {

        $('#numpadTable').fadeIn();

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you I worked well.  But table comes and goes when I clicked to the table

Comment: I worked but some result, by the way i used the css to hide table like display:none property.

Comment: I figured why its happening when I clicked to the button it wrote number to the textbox while doing this it reloads page that's why table goes. I used the onClientClick = "return false;" but this time it doesnt return its value to the textbox.

Comment: Haha. Silly mistake. Glad you caught it ;)

Comment: Yes ;) I got the idea but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Well im not good with asp. If the button is in form then the page might get refreshed.

Comment: Ok, you solved the problem for me thank you for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ASP.NET, `numpadID` is a server control(as you are using `runat="server"`) you need to use [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx). `<%= numpadID.ClientID %>` will Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

*Use*

```
$("#<%= numpadID.ClientID %>").on('click', function () {
    $("#<%= numpadTable.ClientID %>").toggle('show');
});
```

*OR*

You can use [`ClientIDMode.Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) mode then you can continue with your existing code. However I will not recommend it.

---

**As of jQuery 1.7**, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to `.live()`

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="numpadID" runat="server" MaxLength="10"> by the way it is not on the same table with numpadTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to show and hide the table.

```
$("#<%= numpadID.ClientID %>").focus(function () {
    $("#numpadTable").attr('visible','true');
});
```